# Getting an array into a parallel bash script

Tags: dd, bash-array

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding parallel procedures. Atm I'm trying to mass wipe hard drives, so have created a script, however it won't run in parallel.

```
for i in "${!wipe[@]}"; do
       dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/${wipe[$i]} &
wait
```

The dd zeros the disks but it does this one after the other so when doing 8 disks, can be very time consuming.
Thanks

Comment: 1. why iterate over the keys (indices) of $wipe? you're not using the index for anything else, just to get the value...it's easier to just iterate over the values.  e.g. `for d in "${wipe[@]}"; do dd if=/dev/zero of="/dev/$d" & done`.   2. depending on the reason why you're mass-wiping drives, you might want to use [wipe](https://github.com/berke/wipe) or [nwipe](https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe) or similar to securely wipe them instead of `dd`.   3. `wait` tells the shell to wait for the background process to finish, which kind of makes running it in the bg pointless.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, dd currently fits what is required. This has been decided above me I am just automating a process in order to learn bash more. This was just the final hurdle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script as given shouldn't run at all, because you are missing the `done` on the for loop.   This must be an excerpt, and you've left out important parts.

Assuming the missing `done` is after this snippet, the wait is inside the for loop, so you start the `dd` in the background and then `wait` for it to finish before going to the next iteration.

Basically, your indention doesn't match the code shown, and this isn't python.  Unlike python, bash ignores indention.  I'm sure the indention matches what you want, but it's meaningless without the `done` that belongs before the wait.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question at all, the first thing I tried was the changing of my indentation, and clearly the capabilities between bash and python are much different.

Comment: @Earthwormben this *does* answer your question.   Running `wait` immediately after running `dd` in the background tells the shell to wait until the background process is finished before doing anything else.   Also, indentation is irrelevant in shell scripts (about the only time it can make even a tiny difference is inside heredocs or quoted strings)

Comment: @Earthwormben I think you've missed my point.  I have updated the answer to try to clarify it.  Let me know if that helps.  If it still doesn't make sense to you, I can try to improve the answer more.

Comment: It does answer your question--as asked. If the code was written in C, it would look like this: `for ( ... ) { dd ... & ; wait }` That is, each step, it does two things: It executes dd in the background, and then waits--_BEFORE_ going to the next loop iteration. Which is the behavior you observe. But if you add `done` before the wait, the code (in C) would look like `for ( ... ) { dd ... & } ; wait`, which is what you really wanted, correct?

Comment: What it looks like you are doing is expecting indentation level to indicate grouping of commands, like Python does. Bash does not. To bash, it simply ignores and leading and trailing whitespace. So see the code the way bash does: remove all indentation, and maybe you will see why it does not work. C can use { and } to mark blocks of code. Pascal uses keywords BEGIN and END. And to really throw you a confusing twist, Tcl does not have blocks of code at all--"Everything is just text!" as any Tcl programmer will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
parallel -j0 --dryrun dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/{} ::: "${!wipe[@]}"
```

Remove `--dryrun` when the output looks correct.

(Also consider overwriting the harddrives with random data. You can use
https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/rand to generate massive amounts of cryptographically secure pseudo-random data).